# Creating Java library - add Gradle dependency for testing, but don't include it in compiled library (or make it overridable)

Tags: java, android, gradle

I have an Android project and I plan to make one of its components a library. This will be a Java library (jar), as the android dependencies are not needed there.

The problem is that this library depends on RxJava. But I would like it to be dependent on the RxJava version which the **library client** will use, no to be explicitly provided by me in the library's `build.gradle`.

I thought that maybe [Gradle Default dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:configuration_defaults) would be the way to go, but it doesn't provide the RxJava dependency at all and the library module doesn't build.

My `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}

configurations.all {
    pluginTool {
        defaultDependencies { dependencies ->
            dependencies.add(this.project.dependencies.create("io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.0"))
        }
    }
}

sourceCompatibility = "1.7"
targetCompatibility = "1.7"
```

Comment: provided insted compile (in `dependencies` add `provided 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.0'` )

Comment: @Selvin thanks, but it doesn't work (at least for a java module). `Error:(15, 0) Could not find method provided() for arguments [io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.0] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.`. I tried adding `compile.extendsFrom provided` to `configurations` and it compiles but it just includes this version of RxJava and the whole project ends up with both versions of RxJava - it doesn't get replaced by the client one.

Comment: [compileOnly](https://gradle.org/blog/compile-only-dependencies/) (Gradle 2.12) ?

Comment: I tried `compileOnly` and it seems to work, however I use different versions to see if both are attached and both of them appear in External Libraries section. But for now I only have a submodule, not a library on an external server, so it may be that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that this library depends on RxJava. But I would like it to be dependent on the RxJava version which the **library client** will use, no to be explicitly provided by me in the library's `build.gradle`.

I don't know if that's possible because that's not the way dependencies work. [Maven Transitive Dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies) explains this issue a little.

For example, you made a library and used a given version of RxJava, say, `vn`. It implictly means that your lib uses some features of `vn` that are not present in `vn-1` and hopefully won't be deprecated in `vn+1` and later. If a lib client were able to choose any RxJava version, it could arbitrarily pick `vn-1` and your code would not work. You have a hard dependency on `vn` and anyone who uses your library should be aware of it.

There's no problem in providing an explicit dependency in your lib's `build.gradle`. In fact, listing the dependencies will help Gradle resolve the dependency graph, handle conflicts and everything. Here's a bit of what Gradle does: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html

Finally, even if you find a way to achieve the dependency delegation to the lib client, the application can crash during runtime.

Comment: This is what I have seen in some libraries that I use (e.g. sqlbrite). Maybe it makes sense. Btw, I wonder where the downvote came from :P